# WCF with custom SOAP headers vs. WSDL generation at operation level

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have implemented an operation behavior which reads/writes some out-of-bound information in a custom SOAP message header. By means of implementing `IWsdlExportExtension` within the behavior class I also want to alter the WSDL description of the web service in order to reflext those customizations.

```
public class BulkOperationAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior, IWsdlExportExtension
{
    // ...

    public void ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext context)
    {
        // _OperationDescription has been remembered in ApplyDispatchBehavior...
        foreach ( MessageDescription operationMessage in _OperationDescription.Messages )           
        {
            if ( operationMessage.Direction == MessageDirection.Input )
                BulkOperationMessageExtension.AddRequestMessageHeaderDescription(operationMessage.Headers);
            else
                BulkOperationMessageExtension.AddResponseMessageHeaderDescription(operationMessage.Headers);
                    // this extension methods creates a MessageHeaderDescription instance and adds it to the header collection...
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the **resulting WSDL doesn't contain the information**.

Interestingly, when I move the WSDL generation code to a contract behavior class, it works as expected. Unfortunately this is quite cumbersome - every time I use `[BulkOperation]` at the operation level I need to decorate the service contract as well.

The issue is briefly mentioned [here](http://tintoy.snoscillator.net/2012/06/24/wcf-and-out-of-band-info/) but without any deeper explanation.

**My question**: Do you know any workaround for generating custom header WSDL on the level of an operation behavior?